# How to listen websocket periodically in background in android

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, android-workmanager

i am using stomp client in android to connect with server. i have successfully connect with server and on subscribe i am getting message also when application is in foreground and background. i am getting issue after kill app.i am not getting message.
so i have tried work manager for that to run periodically and get subscribe to server.but i am not getting success in that. please help me to over come this issue. here is below my code please check.

i am using work manager 2.6.0beta01

AndrodManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge">
        <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>
```

Above code of manifest where i have initialize it.

Application.kt

```
    class App : Application() {
    val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mStompClient = Stomp.over(
            Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP,
            AppConstant.Base_Url_socket
        )
        mStompClient?.connect()
        mStompClient?.lifecycle()
            ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe { lifecycleEvent: LifecycleEvent ->
                when (lifecycleEvent.type) {
                    LifecycleEvent.Type.OPENED ->  {
                        startWorkManager()
                        Log.e("WebSocket", "Stomp connection opened")
                    }
                    LifecycleEvent.Type.ERROR -> {
                        Log.e("error", lifecycleEvent.exception.message.toString())
                        Log.e("WebSocket", "Stomp connection error")
                    }
                    LifecycleEvent.Type.CLOSED -> Log.e("WebSocket", "Stomp connection closed")
                }
            }?.autoDispose(compositeDisposable)
    }

    companion object {

        var mStompClient: StompClient? = null

        fun startWorkManager(){
            val constraints: Constraints = Constraints.Builder().apply {
                setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            }.build()

              val periodicWorkRequest=  PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                    MyJobService::class.java,
                    PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES
                )
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .addTag(AppConstant.subscribeTag)
                    .build()
            WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext()).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(AppConstant.nameTag,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,periodicWorkRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

in above code i have connect with websocket and start periodic worker.

MyJobService.kt

```
 class MyJobService(var context: Context, var workerParameters: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParameters) {
    val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    lateinit var notificationUtils: NotificationNetworkUtils

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            // Do something
        App.mStompClient = Stomp.over(
                Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP,
                AppConstant.Base_Url_socket
            )
            App.mStompClient?.connect()
            notificationUtils = NotificationNetworkUtils(context)
            var response = ""
            val userId = PreferenceHelper.get<LoginDetail>(AppConstant.PREF_LOGIN)?.id

            if (userId != null) {
                App.mStompClient?.topic("/topic/sendMessageResult/$userId")
                    ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    ?.subscribe { topicMessage: StompMessage ->
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, topicMessage.payload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                        Log.e("hasu", topicMessage.payload)
                        response = topicMessage.payload
                        notificationUtils.startForegroundNotification(response)
                    }
            }

//            val inputData = Data.Builder()
//                .putString("response", response)
//                .build()
            Result.success()
        } catch (error: Throwable) {
            Log.e("workrequest==>", error.message!!)
            Result.failure()
            Result.retry()
        }
    }
}
```

above code is of worker class. where i am listen to websocket and subscribe to channel for get message from it.

Comment: you should user a service to do that, work manager has its limitation like minimum execution time is 15 mins

Comment: yes but service also i think stop working after API level 29. foreground service  we have to use after Android O and its not work after API 29 . i mean say its deprecated think @Quicklearner

Comment: yes you can use it with forground service

Comment: but in android 12 we can not start foreground service while app is in background @Quicklearner

Comment: there is restriction. that's why they give workmanager as solution

Comment: you can run background service continuously just by enabling foreground notification in it , you should search about it more

Comment: i have search on that here is https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/foreground-services link of it. it will not work on android 12 @Quicklearner

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/foreground-services#cases-fgs-background-starts-allowed

Comment: there are special cases where you can implement it

Comment: yes that is exceptional cases but in my requirement chatting i think start foreground is not feasible way to do this as like any other chat application working without start foreground notification for chat

Comment: @HasuSarkar did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing similar issue and struggling to keep my websocket opened in the background using WorkerManager.